All of them in order
The answer to this puzzle describes the left part of the puzzle.
Replace the question mark (to the right) with the correct single-word country in order for the left part of the puzzle to make sense. No duplicates in the list.
Also, notice how one entry is blank (no country can be placed there). You'll notice why once you see what's going on. I'm sure you can add what's missing in order to find the final answer.
 ? ? ?  DENMARK 
 ? ? ?  FINLAND
 ? ? ?  PORTUGAL

 ? ? ? ? 
 ? ? ? ? MONTENEGRO
 ? ? ? ? GEORGIA
 ? ? ? ?    ? 

 ? ? ? ? ? GUINEA 
 ? ? ? ? ? BANGLADESH
 ? ? ? ? ? AFGHANISTAN


The answer to this puzzle is:

 DIGIT GRIDS - and the country Luxembourg will replace that question mark.

Let's see why... The first thing we need to do is work out what might be hiding behind the question marks on the left. So...

 ...how many rows of question marks are there? Ten.

 Is it possible that the ten rows are hiding ten members of a complete set of some kind? ('Complete' since the title mentions 'all of them'...) Well, there aren't that many things that famously come in tens (excluding Biblical commandments and 'Things I Hate About You'!), meaning that one thing immediately jumps to mind: The digits 0-9.

 And look, if we spell out those digits, we end up with three 3-letter words (ONE, TWO and SIX), four 4-letter words (ZERO, FOUR, FIVE and NINE), and three 5-letter words (THREE, SEVEN and EIGHT), which tallies perfectly with the rows presented here!

So how about replacing the question marks with these, as per the title's other instruction - 'in order'...

 (That order being numerical order...) We get:

 ONE DENMARK
 TWO FINLAND
 SIX PORTUGAL

 ZERO [none]
 FOUR MONTENEGRO
 FIVE GEORGIA
 NINE ?

 THREE GUINEA
 SEVEN BANGLADESH
 EIGHT AFGHANISTAN

 Already, there's a sign we may be on to something - the number 'zero' aligns with the row we are told is impossible to fill, suggesting we may be looking to index letters into names, or something like that. In fact, let's do that as our first attempt at exploring where we go next - we end up with the following letters:

 DIG .TG? IDS

 from [D]ENMARK (1), F[I]NLAND (2), PORTU[G]AL (6), [impossible] (0), MON[T]ENEGRO (4), GEOR[G]IA (5), ????????[?]* (9), GU[I]NEA, BANGLA[D]ESH (7), AFGHANI[S]TAN (8), where the name of that '9-country' will be 9 or more letters in length.

This looks very promising...

 If an 'I' is substituted for the impossible-to-index zero-value, and we can get an 'R' for the niner, we can produce the phrase 'DIGIT GRIDS', which perfectly describes the left-hand side of the puzzle, which are all grids containing the names of digits, satisfying our brief.

 What can give us an 'R' in the ninth position of the name of a one-word country (without reusing MONTENEG[R]O for this purpose)? There's only one other sovereign state that will do - LUXEMBOU[R]G! And the puzzle is solved :)


No way not again!!!

@PDT Hehe - way, I'm afraid...! :)

You are my official sniper here it seems. If I counted correctly this is at least the 6th time this year!

Well done! This is the answer. You were slightly faster than @PDT and you also got the correct country and explained it in more detail so tick goes to you.
